# Symfony2 get $_SESSION variable(it was created outside of symfony application)

Tags: php, session, symfony

I controller i can get `$_SESSION['my_var']` ( it was created outside of symfony application, and i need to get it inside symfony controller in symfony way e.g.

`$Request->getSession()->get('my_var')`

But this code always return `NULL` and if i use `$_SESSION['my_var']` i get my result.
I have found [PHPBridgeSessionStorage class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html) but this not work for me, because my session already started.
*So question is how can i get it with symfony functions?*

Answer (score 1):

After some research i have found solution:

`$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['my_var']`

So now i can get access to my variable like this:

`$Request->getSession()->get('my_var')`

Symfony2 Session stores all values per default under a storageKey "_sf2_attributes" (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag)